# I have an array of coordinates, I want to make sure each coordinate occupy its own space

Tags: coordinate-systems, network

I have many dots on a plane, e.g. $(1,1), (3,5), (5,9)$. Imagine each dot is a country. Now I define each country should at least occupy an area of $100$ unit square.(width: 10 unit, height: 10 unit) No dots should be sitting on other dots' occupied area.

So I need an algorithm to rearrange the position of these dots, so that they won't sit within others' area.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So you want to make squares of size $\sqrt{30} \times \sqrt{30}$, right? And you have a condition that the points have to be within these squares? Do they have to be in the centre of the square or ...?

Comment: If there no restrictions on the shape of the area, I think it's possible for any array of coordinates and there is no need to rearrange. Besides, what do you mean "rearrange the position"? If there no restrictions, I can put them far enough away.

Comment: @MattiP. yes at the centre of the square, actually the height and width of the sqaure can be any number too

Comment: @W.mu my goal is to put them as close as possible yet not touching others' occupied area

Comment: You can just make the width $\epsilon$ and the height $\frac{30}{\epsilon}$. $\epsilon$ is some small number here, like $\epsilon = 10^{-12}$. Problems?

Comment: (I see that you changed the numbers now. Well, it doesn't essentially change the solution.)

Comment: In the body if the question you define the width to be $10$ and the height to be $10$. But in your comment you said that they can be "any number". So what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @MattiP. yes it can be any number, just 10 seems more tidy?

Comment: Do the width and height have to be equal? In other words, does it have to be precisely a square?

Comment: what if i want to make it a function? like the input for the width of the square now is 10, how can i come up with the new positions of all the dots?

Comment: @MattiP. yes it will be a square

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to generate $n$ squares of size $d \times d$ on a plane. Here is the most straightforward approach:

Take the Cartesian $xy$ coordinate plane, and in specific the positive $x$-axis. Divide the $x$-axis into the following intervals:
$$
I _i = \left\{x = (i-1)\times d \dots i \times d \right\}\qquad i = 1, 2, 3, \dots , n
$$
In other words, slice the axis, starting from $0$, into $n$ intervals of length $d$. The interval $i$ serves as the base of square number $i$.

The squares $S_i$ are generated from these intervals $I_i$ only by defining that the height is $d$:
$$
S_i = \text{set of points $(x,y)$ so that $x\in I_i$ and $0 \leq y\leq d$}
$$
Can you visualize the squares now? The centre points of the squares are easy to calculate, they are
$$
C_i = (x,y) = \left(i+\frac{d}{2}, \frac{d}{2} \right)
$$

Comment: I think I got this!! Thanks so much, I m going to write a function to do it in my program